# Generate if-for statement

Tags: fpga, verilog, xilinx, hdl, vivado

Can we declare Generate if-for statement?

```
module prac#(parameter m=3)
(input x, input[2:0]a,b,output[2:0]c);
wire [2:0]f[0:3];
genvar i;
generate
if(!x) begin : d2
    for(i=0;i<=m;i=i+1) begin:dd
    assign f[i]=(a & b);  end
end
endgenerate
endmodule
```

It is saying that 'x' is not a constant.
I want to instantiate a module multiple times based on control signal. Here x is my control signal. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you think your code should infer in hardware?

Comment: What would be required to happen if the input `x` was zero, and then changes to one?

Comment: Using `x` as an identifier seems like a very poor choice since that character also has special meaning.

Comment: @TomCarpenter.        Sir, sorry I didn't go for hardware at this time. I have all the data available and in that clock pulse itself I want to perform computation on all data points in parallel. x- indicates the data is available to perform operation. I'm learning verilog HDL and have seen the generate if and generate for statements which instantiate and create blocks without explicit instantiation of each one. Please let me know if I'm wrong and are there any other things I've to keep in mind while using instantiations

Answer (score 2):

What you have written is:

*"If signal X is true I don't need any hardware.

  If signal X is false I want to have some hardware which does..... "*

Hardware either exists or it does not exist. It can't just disappear into nothing or appear out of nothing.

All you can do is have the hardware (always) present end then you
can use it or not.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not control instantiation of modules at run time. Don't confuse a **hardware description language** with a conventional programming language. You must instantiate, once and for all, every module you will ever need. Your HDL code then specifies ways of controlling data flow and conditional access to the  modules.

Comment: I have read that using Generate construct we can instantiate module multiple times which will create blocks of hardware.

Comment: Yes, but that can only happen at compile time (or better, synthesis time).

Comment: Then `x` can't be a "control signal" that changes after synthesis. `x` must be a constant value, which is what the tools are trying to tell you.

Comment: yes. x is constant but it depends on the previous operations. As there is a data dependency I've used control signal which just indicates that the operation was completed and gives one otherwise zero.

Comment: No! The value of `x` **can not** depend on **anything** that is not a constant known to the tools at compile time. The value of `x` can **never, ever, ever** change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80068/discussion-between-sandeep-i-and-elliot-alderson).

Answer (score 0):

Make X a parameter instead of an input. Inputs can change over time, parameters are fixed per instantiation.

You also need to assign something to F in an "else" branch.